# The most optimized repeated cross validation

Tags: r, loops, cross-validation, r-caret

I want to perform 5-fold cross validation 10 times and output accuracy. Let's consider my function:

```
library(caret)
cross_validation <- function(y, x) {
  acc <- c()
  idx <- 1:length(y)
  
  for (j in 1:10) {
    folds <- createFolds(y, k = 5, list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)
    
    
    for (i in 1:5) {
      training <- idx[-unlist(folds[i])]
      
      model <- glm(y[training] ~ ., data = x[training, ], family = binomial())
      
      preds <- predict(model, newdata = x[unlist(folds[i]), ], type = "response")
      
      preds[preds>0.5] <- 1
      
      preds[preds <=0.5] <- 0

      acc[i] <- confusionMatrix(as.factor(y[unlist(folds[i])]), as.factor(preds))$overall[1]
    }
  }
    mean(acc, na.rm = T)
}
```

Also notice that it really works on example:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- sample(0:1,100,T)
df <- data.frame("Norm" = rnorm(100), "Exp" = rexp(100))
> cross_validation(y, x)
[1] 0.45
```

However I found it little inconvenient and inefficient. I think that I code it in most slow way as possible (but also most intuitive). The problem of this code is double loop. I was thinking if there is any possibility to omit it, however I have no idea how. Do you think that double loop it avoidable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `train` function in caret with a repeated cv:

```
y = sample(0:1,100,T)
df = data.frame("Norm" = rnorm(100), "Exp" = rexp(100))
ctrl  = trainControl(method="repeatedcv",number=5,repeats=10)
set.seed(42)

res = train(y=factor(y),x=df,trControl=ctrl,method="glm")
```

You get the overall accuracy:

```
   Accuracy      Kappa parameter    Resample
1 0.5500000  0.0000000      none Fold1.Rep01
2 0.5789474  0.0000000      none Fold2.Rep01
3 0.5714286  0.0000000      none Fold3.Rep01
4 0.5500000  0.0000000      none Fold4.Rep01
5 0.4000000 -0.2903226      none Fold5.Rep01
6 0.4000000 -0.2631579      none Fold1.Rep02
> res
Generalized Linear Model 

100 samples
  2 predictor
  2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold, repeated 10 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 80, 81, 79, 80, 80, 80, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy   Kappa      
  0.5196291  -0.07190123
```

This gives the accuracy across all training folds:

```
head(res$resample)
   Accuracy      Kappa parameter    Resample
1 0.5500000  0.0000000      none Fold1.Rep01
2 0.5789474  0.0000000      none Fold2.Rep01
3 0.5714286  0.0000000      none Fold3.Rep01
4 0.5500000  0.0000000      none Fold4.Rep01
5 0.4000000 -0.2903226      none Fold5.Rep01
6 0.4000000 -0.2631579      none Fold1.Rep02
```